# Rearranging one array in accordance to another

Tags: c, arrays, vector

Original Values (Array 1): 10 20 30 40 50

Re-arranged Indexes (Array 2): 4 2 0 1 3

How would I rearrange the first array in accordance to the indices of the second array? For example, 50 would be the first value outputted since it is the fourth index and 4 is the first value in Array 2. Thank you so much in advance.

```
i = 0;
while (i <= n) {
  scanf("%d", vector1[vector2[i]]);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us something that you've already tried? Here on Stack Overflow, we prefer to 'correct' existing code rather than providing new code.

Comment: Hi, I added some code.

Comment: right idea, wrong function. try `printf()`

Comment: When I use printf, it still says the execution is interrupted because I am using an illegal array index.

Comment: That's probably due to `(i <= n)` as your while condition. If `n` is the number of elements in `vector2` then that loop should limit to `(i < n)`. Hard saying without a real [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the `vector2` and use its values as indicies by accessing values from `vector1`

Code below maybe not to 100% correct I just wrote it down.

```
for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
  newVector[i] = vector1[vector2[i]] 
}
```

So the output would be: 50 30 10 20 40